# java applet (Drawing a happy or smiley face)

Tags: java, applet

I intend to draw a happy face using java, and this is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class HappyFace extends Japplet
{
    public void paint(Graphics canvas)
    {
        super.paint(canvas);
        canvas.drawOval(100, 50, 200, 200);
        canvas.fillOval(155, 100, 10, 20);
        canvas.fillOval(230, 100, 10, 20);
        canvas.drawArc(150, 160, 100, 50, 180, 180);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
HappyFace.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class HappyFace extends japplet
                               ^
  symbol: class japplet
HappyFace.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        super.paint(canvas);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class HappyFace
2 errors
```

Comment: Note that Java is case sensitive. `Japplet`, `japplet`, and `JApplet` are all different. Only the last one is correct.

Comment: See [our help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for instructions on how to format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no super class called `Japplet` to extend. It must be `JApplet` just as the import statement says.
You need to make the class declaration as follows: `public class HappyFace extends JApplet`

Comment: Strangely, the error message has different case than the code. Or maybe the OP typed them differently than they actually are.

Comment: You're right, but I didn't notice that. Perhaps, the OP tried different scenarios but doesn't know that the case matters. Anyway, the right solution is posted in the answer, and we hope this will help them solve their problem.